# ionic build android error:

Tags: android, ionic-framework

when I do ionic build android , I am getting this error...I am a beginner and cant find the exact solution anywhere...

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom'.
  >   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Do you have the SDK updated? You can check if there is any updates from "Android SDK Manager". There you can update the Android Tools. Apparently you are missing the required alpha version.

Comment: yes the sdk is updated.